# Swashbuckle replace Type with other Type

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

I have this controller in my asp.net-core web-api project:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<ActualModel>> Get()
    {
        return new List<ActualModel>()
        {
            new ActualModel { StringValue1 = "SomeString" },
            new ActualModel { StringValue1 = "MoreString" }
        };
    }
}
```

The only method in this controller returns a list of "ActualModel". The definition of it looks like this:

```
public class ActualModel
{
    public string StringValue1 { get; set; }
}
```

And my `swashbuckle` generated Swagger-UI shows it like this:

[image: The Swagger-UI Schema representation of the Model]

But I would like the `Swashbuckle` to generate the Swagger-Specification so that it not contains the "ActualModel" but the following model instead:

```
public class OtherModel
{
    public string StringValue2 { get; set; }
    public int IntValue1 { get; set; }
}
```

I've noticed there is a function that I think I can use for this:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.MapType<ActualModel>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "string" });
```

But I can't figure out how I get the "OtherModel" to be generated into an `OpenApiSchema` so that it replaces the "ActualModel" nor can I find information or examples about it.

I tried giving it the full class name with namespace and without the namespace, I googled for "Swashbuckle replace Type with other Type" and "Swashbuckle MapType" but I cant find any examples which show how to simply replace one type with another type that is defined in the application.

**Background:** The above is just an example of course. In a "real" project I have generic and hierarchical class-definitions that I want to return in my controller but I have a Serializer in between the value the controller returns and the actual network output which changes the data structure to another, more simple structure for use on a Typescript side. That's why I want to replace the swashbuckle generated model definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could just *tell* swagger what you are producing if for example it's not obvious because of templates or a hierarchy:

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(OtherModel[]), 200)]             // <--- This line
public ActionResult<List<ActualModel>> Get()
{
    return new List<ActualModel>()
    {
        new ActualModel { StringValue1 = "SomeString" },
        new ActualModel { StringValue1 = "MoreString" }
    };
}
```

However, it's your job to make sure they are actually compatible, there are no checks.

Comment: I've seen this line dozens of times and did not come to the conclusion that I could do it this way. Thanks for pointing out the obvious :D

Comment: This solution is 1st static (compile time) and 2nd needs editing in every place you use the model. Isn't there a centralized way in SwaggerGen to say at runtime "oh, whenever you see a model of type A (input or output) just substitute it with B". I need that for a plugin system when each endpoint may take as input (or give output) slightly different objects based on which plugin is used.